# Graphic design Portfolio

Tags: adobe-photoshop, adobe-illustrator, print-design, portfolio

In my portfolio should i affiliate real projects photos or only the original psd or ai file? [image]

Comment: You can use photos if they are *good* photos. I would *not* use the the you posted.

Answer (score 1):

It is good practice to include both! Potential employers want to see how you work and how you can mock up a design like this (native files), and it is great to see that a project has come to life, so showing real photos is a plus! That means you were hired, they liked your idea, they implemented it, and now people enjoy it every day. It is a great piece to include in your portfolio and shows variety.

Depending on how your portfolio is laid out, I would encourage you to show a side by side (or two-up on a single page) to showcase the pitched mockup and the final printed design.

One note, I wouldn't use the picture that you have here unless it is the only one you have. I would take a photo when the space is done and everything is clean and nice. I would use a nice camera and take images at multiple angles so that you can present your final design in the best possible way.